# how to use cordova-plugin-dialogs?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am a beginner in Cordova and I would just like to find a way to post a notification in an Android smartphone.
So I created a project cordova very simple and with absolutely no particular code but simply an index.html page and an index.js which must show me a notification on the smartphone when launching the application.
But that remains unsuccessful ... Do you know how the plugin used: cordova-plugin-dialogs?

Here is the link of the project github : https://github.com/jboucly/CordovaNotification.git

Thank You !! :)

Comment: try https://ionicframework.com/docs/ for your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well create something like

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Cordova Dialogue Plugin Documanetation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/) to know everything it offers.

To know how it works visit [Tutorials Point - Dialogues](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_dialogs.htm). It is easily understandable and also shows examples.
[Dialogues Cordova - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G50qwpsl4Bs). This is a youtube video that I dont really recommend but you may watch it if the above tutorials are not satisfactory.